# PHP AJAX PDF Reader just like book

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, slide

Does anyone know how to build something like the functionality shown here: [like sliding a book](http://www.bauhaus.se/kampanjblad1)

I want to load PDF content, so that users can read all of my PDFs like a slideshow.

I'd like to use PHP, MySQL and JQuery, but I haven't found any JQuery plugin that functions like a PDF reader.

Comment: Thanks to Chris W for editing

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is a solution in AJAX, jQuery or Javascript yet. You have to build it yourself or...

what you can do is convert each page in PHP to JPG (there are a lot of classes to do that), after that you can then load the pages in a jQuery Slideshow or load the images external from a flash file.

Comment: is there a php programm that take input of my pdf file and output jpeg. that mean when my pdf file contains 40 pages, it will create 40 images

Comment: You can use a class like this: [link](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5260-PHP-Convert-PDF-files-to-JPEG-images-using-ImageMagick.html) .... or .... [link](http://www.binpress.com/app/pdf-to-jpg-converter/319)